# Why doesn't LinkedHashSet implement List?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, set, linkedhashset

To my understanding, a `List` is an *ordered* collection of items. And a `Set` is a collection of *unique* items.

Now my question is, why does `LinkedHashSet`, which describes an *ordered* collection of *unique* items, implement the `Set` interface (=> *unique*), but not the `List` interface (=> *ordered*)?

One possible argument is that `List` is intended for random access datastructures, but that would be invalidated by the fact that `LinkedList` doesn't have "true" random access either. In fact, `LinkedHashSet` is backed by an internal linked list. Also the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for `List` says otherwise:

> Note that these [positional index] operations may execute in time proportional to the index value for some implementations.

Comment: Because a `List` allows duplicates.

Comment: because as the name suggest is a ***SET***

Comment: `In fact, LinkedHashSet is backed by a LinkedList` - wrong. It is backed by an internal implementation of a linked list, not by java.util.LinkedList.

Comment: @Eran thanks, I updated my question

Comment: @Tom the list interface doesn't specify that it has to allow duplicates. it even says: "It is not inconceivable that someone might wish to implement a list that prohibits duplicates"

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ that's just the class' name, but the behaviour suggests that it's both a set and a (immutable) list

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I have a suggestion for how you could find out: write a class that implements `List` and delegates all its operations to an internal `LinkedHashSet`.  Find out where the implementation gets messy.

Comment: This is not opinion based. This is a question about what were the reasons of `LinkedHashSet` not implementing `List` interface when it was created by Sun/Oracle.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I went ahead and implemented a version of `LinkedHashSet` that implements `List`: https://gist.github.com/Felk/185fec05c0d081908ec668a3fb208723 looks fine to me

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak - Exactly, the class was created by Sun/Oracle. It is vanishingly unlikely anyone here is close enough to the designers of the Java class library to be able to accurately explain why the class is the way it is. Hence answers are going to share our opinions on why we might have done it this way were we in their place. Which we're not. Furthermore this question is not asking anybody to solve a problem the OP is having - it's not like we can change the Java standard library for them.

Answer (score 3):

If it implemented a `List` you would be able to use it as a `List`:

```
List list = new LinkedHashSet();
```

This might lead to issues with duplicates which don't appear in `Set` but are allowed in `List`.

In other words, you shouldn't declare that something is a `List` when it doesn't allow duplicates even if it holds the order and allows adding, getting, removing and checking the size.

> Unlike sets, lists typically allow duplicate elements
>   [--List documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: From that link: "It is not inconceivable that someone might wish to implement a list that prohibits duplicates, by throwing runtime exceptions when the user attempts to insert them . . ."

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede "...but we expect this to be rare"

Comment: Rare, not prohibited.  Accepting duplicate elements is *not* a characteristic of `List`.  It's a characteristic of common implementations of `List`.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede And that's the issue. It would be quite confusing when you have a list which doesn't allow dupe and you don't know the actual type, because you only work with `List`. Although the interface itself might allow it, it isn't what the developer would expect and that counts more (at least on my count, since code readability is a big plus).

Comment: `List.add(E e)` documentation says "Appends the specified element to the end of this list (optional operation).". The method returns boolean saying whether collection has been changed by the call, as specified in `Collection.add(E e)` documentation: "Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the call. (Returns false if this collection does not permit duplicates and already contains the specified element.)".

Comment: Hence, having `List list = new LinkedHashSet();` and `list.add(1); list.add(1);` returning first `true` and then `false` looks like logical scenario to me.

Answer (score 0):

because LinkHashSet is  class which implements set interface . List and Set has its own functionality List allowed duplicates while set do not allowed duplicates but if you want linear order insertion  in a HastSet then LinkedHashSet is used with no duplicates in itself ..

```
Set s = new LinkedHashSet();
```

is the implementation of a set in which insertion order is preserved and  duplicates do not allowed..

Comment: List does not necessarily allow duplicates, please see the other answers and comments.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?source=hp&q=list+allow+duplicate+values%3F&oq=list+allow+duplicate+values%3F&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l3.588.5222.0.5584.13.11.0.0.0.0.350.2066.2-6j2.8.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..5.8.2059.0..0j35i39k1j0i67k1j0i20k1.utT8YhyMEcY              please gather the knowledge then comment